# Xcode error lexical or preprocessor?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, smtp, directory

I am making an app that involves a form. I have my `SMTP` framework but I can not build it because it gives me the error you can see in the screenshot below. I also have the framework to show how I've set it up. Can anybody help?

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: NS Data + Base64Additions.h file...
```

[image: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue]

[image]

Comment: Can you expand the left pane to see the whole error message. The "..." part isn't very informative.

Comment: it just says not found after that